# React Randomly Positioned Images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, frontend

I have an issue about positioning images in React. I want a simple UI like this
[image]

In these cards, when 2 images come to UI, UI should be like first one. When 4 images come to UI, UI should be like this. I want to make this component dynamic. I want to give images to the component and want images to be positioned according to the number of images. Is there any npm module that runs like this? Or how can I write a component like that?

Thanks

Comment: From an aesthetics standpoint, random placement wouldn't be pretty, imagine you have two images but they both get placed all the way to the right - the UI looks broken. Perhaps you can use css grid?

Comment: This is a customer project and customer wants like this

Comment: You can calculate position of images based on grid (where is should be in regular style) but add to it some small random factor. That should solve the problem I think.

Comment: You can look into grid positioning for this. You can have set of classes that you apply to your images that are rendered as list elements and the set of classes are applied randomly to the `li`s.